# Link to and display file as plaintext

Tags: html, jekyll

I have a file on my server `/path/to/my/file/file.extension`.

I want to link to that file on a webpage:

```html
<a href='/path/to/my/file/file.extension'>File</a>
```

When the user clicks that link I want the server to serve that file as a plaintext document that the browser will navigate to and display. Currently, however, clicking that link brings up the "Save file" dialog and prompts the user to open or save the file to their computer.

The `type` tag seems to be non-functional:

```html
<a type='text/plain' href='/path/to/my/file/file.extension'>File</a>
```

Comment: Could you clarify if you use the native Jekyll server or another server (apache, nginx...) ? Your issue is not Jekill-specific but server related.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType text/plain .txt
```

This avoids .txt files from downloading and makes your browser to show them.

If you are dealing with a Jekyll project, you have to create a htaccess file without the starting dot like `htaccess` then put below content in it. after building the project Jekyll will automatically build proper `.htaccess` file and you will be good to go :)

```
---
layout: none
permalink: .htaccess
---

AddType text/plain .c .js .php
```

Comment: Assuming [this guide](https://davidegan.me/adding-a-htaccess-file-to-a-jekyll-site/) is accurate, no luck.

Comment: What exactly is your file extension?

Comment: Ok so You have to specify them like  `AddType text/plain .c .js .php`. I tried it myself and it's working fine :\

Comment: You have ```.htaccess``` in the root of your Jekyll project, and that is the only line in it, and it works after rebuilding and serving?

Comment: :) oh no, as far as I know Jekyll doesn't like files starting with a dot. I updated the answer, please refer to it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198258/discussion-between-michael-bianconi-and-masoudmanson).